# Kendo UI Scheduler Resource Big data hang week view

Tags: performance, kendo-ui, scheduler

I have 400 resources list. when i use scheduler with big list it hangs week/Day view and browser become unresponsive specially for week and day view.(Evets are not loaded in my case)
I have edited an example in dojo which contains 200 resources and performance goes slows down
See this one

Please help how performance can be improving

[DOJo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UZIso)

Answer (score 0):

Only option for you is to:

a. add items dynamically via [pushCreate()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-pushCreate)

b. limit number of rows

See official KendoUI forum post: [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/performance-b295d6c2ac6d#phhZfSRh20-VjIxpJsd7DQ)